# What is the best way to use ASM and ACM in face detection

Tags: python, c++, image-processing, face-recognition

I am trying to make the face expression decision. First of all, I need to detect face from a video. According to my research, I found two different algorithm for face detection.

1. What should I choose between ASM and ACM algorithm?
2. What is the best solution to detect a face as algorithm?
3. Also what is the best programming language between Pyton and C++ for image processing? I mean as image processing language supporting image processing libraries such as OpenCV.